# Laplace transform of the integral of the solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I have the following differential equation $y'+4y=11t^7$ with the initial condition $y(0)=3$

I need to find the following laplace transform
$$L\left\{\int_0^t y(\mathcal{T})   d\mathcal{T}\right\}$$

I'm unsure of what to use for $y(\mathcal{T})$ and how to then start it off

Can anyone provide any help?

Comment: Or in other words, if $z(t)=\int_0^ty(\tau)d\tau$, then $z''+4z'=11t^7$ with $z(0)=0$ and $z'(0)=3$ and you are looking for ${\scr L}\{z\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: we have
$$\mathscr{L}\left(\int_0^t f(\tau)\,d\tau\right)=\frac{F(s)}{s},$$
where $F(s)=\mathscr{L}(f(t))$.

Comment: So L{f(t)}= (55440+3s^8)/(s^8(s+4)) = F(s).  Therefore is the answe then (55440+3s^8)/(s^9(s+4))?

Comment: @LolaLynch Exactly

Comment: this makes so much more sense now, Thankyou